# Unable to find pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to use pattern matcher to find the specific pattern and I have created the regex pattern through this [website](http://regexr.com/) and it shows that the pattern is found in the text file I wanted to read.

> Extra info.: This code works like this : Start reading the textfile,
>   when meet >D10, enter another loop and get the information until the
>   next >D10 is found. Loop this process until EOF.

My sample text file:

```
D14*
Y7620D03*
X247390Y66680D03*
X251540Y160150D03*
G01Y136780*
G03X-374970Y133680I3100J0*    
D17*
Y7620D03*
X247390Y66680D03*
X251540Y160150D03*
G01Y136780*
G03X-374970Y133680I3100J0*
```

My pattern code in java:

```
private final Pattern PinNamePattern = compile("(D[1-9][0-9])\\*");
private final Pattern LocationXYPattern = compile("^(G0[1-3])?(X|Y)(-?[\\d]+)(D0[1-3])?\\*",Pattern.MULTILINE);
private final Pattern LocationXYIJPattern = compile("^(G0[1-3])?X(-?[\\d]+)?Y(-?[\\d]+)?I?(-?[\\d]+)?J?(-?[\\d]+)?(D0[1-3])?\\*",Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

My code in java:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher pinNameMatcher = PinNamePattern.matcher(line);
    //If found Aperture Name
    if (pinNameMatcher.find()) {
        currentApperture = pinNameMatcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(currentApperture);
        pinNameMatcher.reset();
        //Start matching Location X Y I J     
        //Will keep looping as long as next aperture name not found
        //Second While loop
        while (!(pinNameMatcher.find()) ) {
            line = br.readLine();
            Matcher locXYMatcher = LocationXYPattern.matcher(line);
            Matcher locXYIJMatcher = LocationXYIJPattern.matcher(line);
            LineNumber++;
            if (locXYMatcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("XY FOUND");
                if (locXYIJMatcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println("XYIJ FOUND");
                }
            }
```

However, when I'm using java to read, the pattern just simply cannot be found. Is there anything I missed out or am I doing it wrong? I have tried removing the "^" and MULTILINE flag but the pattern is still not found.

Comment: Is that the complete code for the java Pattern side of things?

Looks like there are a few steps missing like using Pattern.compile then the Matcher.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: I think Martin is right.  The problem probably isn't with your patterns.  You'll need to provide more code.

Comment: @ajb I have updated my question with more code information and what my code's purpose is. Thanks in advance

Comment: @JamesYTL, what processes G-code in Java?

Comment: @MattTimmermans this is a part of image processing files I have to extract information from.

Comment: Oh.  That language is usually used to control CNC machines - mills, lathes, plasma cutters, plotters, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex looks and works fine, it's possible you aren't searching it properly.

```
String s = "G03X-374970Y133680I3100J0*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(G0[1-3])?X(-?[\\d]+)?Y(-?[\\d]+)?I?(-?[\\d]+)?J?(-?[\\d]+)?(D0[1-3])?\\*");

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group(0);
    System.out.println(s); // prints G03X-374970Y133680I3100J0*
}
```

In your updated code, you are looking for the second and third pattern only when the first pattern matches, which is probably not what you want. Try using this as a foundation and improving upon it:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher pinNameMatcher = PinNamePattern.matcher(line);
    if (pinNameMatcher.find()) {
        currentApperture = pinNameMatcher.group(0);
        System.out.println(currentApperture);
    }

    Matcher locXYMatcher = LocationXYPattern.matcher(line);
    if (locXYMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(locXYMatcher.group(0));
    }

    Matcher locXYIJMatcher = LocationXYIJPattern.matcher(line);
    if (locXYMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(locXYIJMatcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with more code information and what my code's purpose is. Thanks in advance

Comment: Found the root cause. I need to add another pinNameMatcher within the second while loop to start another matching process so that it doesn't use the pattern matcher in the first while loop. Still gonna mark yours as answer as I found this solution through your code.